# what are the pre-requisites and practices for multidimensional cube Designing ( during analysis phase)?

Tags: ssas, multidimensional-cube

I'm assigned to design multidimensional cube in SSAS.
As I am very new to SSAS, and currently this is in analysis phase.
Just wanted to see , is there any standard process or guideline should I follow or any general questions should I prepare prior to cube designing?

One thing client specifically mentioned about the volume of data as

> One service area has 3 million rows, 3 years of data

Does it mean, we should plan for partition strategy ? if yes then what are the things should I be looking ? one thing comes in my mind

- what field should we consider to split the cube (am I heading in right direction ?)

What are the other factor should I consider during analysis ?

Answer (score 1):

SSAS design is a large topic with different angels. If i were in your shoes, I'd google for "SSAS Design" or something along those lines to learn more. For example, here's a model chapter from a book provided by Microsoft themselves: https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2812063

I'd skip for partitioning at this stage. See how it performs first and tune it later if really necessary. Usually partitioning is done on some accumulating field , like a date, where old data is not processed daily and only the latest data (partition) is updated (processed). This of course depends on the data you're dealing with.